# How to customize user edit page drupal 7?

Tags: users

I need to change the order in which things are on the user edit page in Drupal 7.  I have tried modifying `page-user-edit.tpl.php` and `user-profile-edit.tpl.php`, but it doesn't seem to ever get there. What can I do?

Comment: The order of which "things" ?

Comment: I found out if you are logged in as admin you cannot see the effects of page-user-edit.tpl.php
only people who are not admin can see the changes you made.  pretty crazy in my opinion!  I stumbled upon this information by accident.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a little different for Drupal 7... The structure of the file name would be `page--user--edit.tpl.php` (for D7) as opposed to `page-user-edit.tpl.php` (for D6).

Also, remember to clear the cache after you make any such changes so that they're recognized.

Hope that helps... :)

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to change the order of the fields in the user profile as they appear on the user profile edit page in Drupal 7, navigate to "Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings" and then click on the "Manage Fields" tab.  You can the use the slider (or row weights) to rearrange the order of the fields.

If you also want to change the order these fields appear in the profile when it is displayed (as opposed to edited), use the "Manage Display" tab.

Remember to save when you're done.