# How to put a link / menu at the top of the edit-user profile page?

Tags: routes, users, forms

How can I put a link / menu in the edit-user-profile page, in the upper right corner? This link will open a new page with a form created. I've been watching a few examples but I could not understand.Sorry for the question, the more I'm starting.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Answer depends on many factors you didn't tell. Most important is what theme are you using? What have you tried? Are you subtheming yet? Have you followed [similat questions](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/73770/16495) and to what effect?

Comment: The theme is scratch, I've tried to use hook_menu (), but got no effect, but as a beginner I'm not sure if it is the best way to hook_menu.

Comment: Please read the older question I linked. I'm pretty sure it already shows you a pretty good way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your problem is with the link and not the form, I have done the following to accomplish something similar in the past:

- create a new block
- enter the link information in the block (you can also do this with a straight menu and use a block menu module)
- put the block in the appropriate section of the page where you want it to appear
- restrict it to only    "user/*/edit"        pages